# Border not appearing when there is a border radius set in chrome 15

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, rounded-corners

I have the following code:
HTML:

```
<div id="login" class="transparent-div login_leaf_class">

<input class="pointer login_fields_button" id="submit_button" type="submit" title="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.login_leaf_class
{
    border:solid #000 !important;
     border-top-left-radius:70% 60% ;
    border-bottom-right-radius:70% 60%;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:70% 50%;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:70% 50%;
}
div#login
{
    position:relative;
    padding:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-right:5%;
    color:#0000;
    float:right;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    font-weight:900;
    background:#FFB3FF;
    background:rgba(255,179,255,0.8);
}
.login_fields_button
{
    float:right;
    display:inline;
    background:#003300;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:900;
    padding:4px;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:0 !important;
     border-top-left-radius:99.9% 100% !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius:99.9% 100% !important;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:99.9% 100% !important;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:99.9% 100% !important;
    border:solid #fff !important;
}
```

The problem  is, the border appears to be coming right in FireFox. Everything worked fine as long as i had chrome14 too, but recently when i updated to chrome 15, the border is appearing at only 2 corners.
See the following screenshots:
[image: This is normal scenario] [image: This is how it looks in chrome 15]
What should i do here?? Is this is a bug??
http://jsfiddle.net/uMYfp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give it a `border-radius` of 4px or more, it works.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uMYfp/3/)

Also, you don't need those `!important`s, that is a bad practice.

Comment: Its a fragment from a large code that needs this `!important` and apart from that, i am quite interested to know why the border that appeared in previous version of chrome disapeared all at once and i have to increase the border-radius??

Comment: Yeah, seems like a bug. Its not that I don't understand specificity, its just that i am too lazy, lol...  i will change that. Thanks a lot.